# Investigate on convergence and absolute convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

How to investigate on convergence and absolute convergence the following integral: $$\int \limits_0^1 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{(\sqrt{x} - x)^n}$$ for all real values of $n$?

I've tried to make a comparison test. In order to do this I needed some upper bound, but I didn't know how to pick it.

**UPD**

As @zhw. pointed I made substitution $x = 1/y$ and got $$\int \limits_1^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin y \cdot y^{n - 2}}{(\sqrt{y} - 1)^n}dy + \int \limits_{\pi/2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin y \cdot y^{n - 2}}{(\sqrt{y} - 1)^n}dy$$

For the first integral I want to use Taylor expansion for $\sqrt{y}$ at $y = 1$ and also the numerator can be bounded by some constant: $$\int \limits_1^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin y \cdot y^{n - 2}}{(\sqrt{y} - 1)^n}dy < \int \limits_1^{\pi/2} \frac{c}{(\sqrt{y} - 1)^n}dy \sim \int \limits_1^{\pi/2} \frac{c}{(1+ \frac{y - 1}{2} + O((y - 1)^2) - 1)^n}dy = \int \limits_1^{\pi/2} \frac{c}{(\frac{y - 1}{2} + O((y - 1)^2))^n}dy$$ .

I don't really know how to proceed further. And also I don't like the jump with equivalence.

For the right integral I probably could say that as $y \to \infty \Rightarrow (\sqrt{y} - 1)^n \sim y^{n/2}$, but again I want to be fully correct with this step.

It seems like it is converge for $n < 1$.

I can't say anything about absolute convergence.

Comment: Is $n$ a positive integer? If it is, say so.

Comment: @zhw. It could be any real value. Just understood that binomial expansion has nothing to do with this integral.

Comment: Well OK, but $n$ is a less than stellar choice to denote any real value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Since $\sqrt x - x$ has a simple zero at $1,$ the integral diverges for $n\ge 1.$ For $n<1,$ make the change of variables $x = 1/y.$

Comment: Can you please clarify how did you conclude that the integral diverges for $n \geq 1$? I don't see how a simple root and $n$ are connected...And is it important to root to be simple?

Comment: @user23316192  I'm saying $\sqrt x - x$ lies between $c(1-x),C(1-x)$ for certain constants  $c,C.$ Therefore $1/f(x)^n$ is like $1/(1-x)^n$ there. If the zero were not simple, things would blow up even worse.